# mongoosejs or statement with objectid

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Can I "traverse" through an ObjectID with an OR statement using mongoose.js?

An example would be something like this:

```
var confName = 'something';
finding = finding.or([
            { 'home_team.conference.name': confName },
            { 'away_team.conference.name': confName }
        ]);
finding.exec(function(err, models) {
     ...
```

`home_team` and `away_team` are both ObjectID's pointing to the Team Schema which has an embedded doc `conference` in it.

Right now this isn't working for me and I'm not sure if I this isn't possible or if I'm just not doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.  You'll need to either store the name in addition to the id on that document (denormalized data is common in mongo schemas) or search for "teams" with that conference name, and then search for something like

```
finding.or([
  { home_team: {$in: teamIds}},
  { away_team: {$in: teamIds}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks ... using `in` was going to be my next option, but it just didn't seem as good.